# Android Parcelable: RuntimeException: Unmarshalling unknown type code

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I'm trying to pass an object from one activity to another. I followed this tutorial [enter link description here](http://shri.blog.kraya.co.uk/2010/04/26/android-parcel-data-to-pass-between-activities-using-parcelable-classes/) but I'm getting the exception:

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@41ed4e70: 
Unmarshalling unknown type code 6357091 at offset 332

My classes are:

```
public class Venue implements Parcelable{

private int id;
private String name;
@SerializedName("address")
private String location;
@SerializedName("lat")
private double latitude;
@SerializedName("lon")
private double longitude;
@SerializedName("postal_code")
private String postalCode;
private String country;
private String phone;
private String website;
@SerializedName("foursquare_id")
private String foursquareId;
@SerializedName("location_id")
private int locationId;
private String city;
@SerializedName("Occurrence")
private Occurrence occurrence;

public Venue(){}

public Venue(int id, String name, String location){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.location = location;
}

public Venue(Parcel in){
    readFromParcel(in);
}

/**
 * Clase para recuperar los datos de un parcel, IMPORTANTE leerlos en el mismo orden que se escribieron!
 * @param in Parcel con los datos a leer
 */
private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
    this.id = in.readInt();
    this.name = in.readString();
    this.location = in.readString();
    this.latitude = in.readDouble();
    this.longitude = in.readDouble();
    this.occurrence = in.readParcelable(Occurrence.class.getClassLoader());
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(this.id);
    dest.writeString(this.name);
    dest.writeString(this.location);
    dest.writeDouble(this.latitude);
    dest.writeDouble(this.longitude);
    dest.writeParcelable(this.occurrence, flags);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Venue> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Venue>() {
    public Venue createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Venue(in);
    }

    public Venue[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Venue[size];
    }
};

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}
public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}
public double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public String getPostalCode() {
    return postalCode;
}

public void setPostalCode(String postalCode) {
    this.postalCode = postalCode;
}

public Occurrence getOccurrence() {
    return occurrence;
}

public void setOccurrence(Occurrence occurrence) {
    this.occurrence = occurrence;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}
```

}

```
public class Occurrence implements Parcelable{
private int id;
@SerializedName("start_date")
private Date startDate;
@SerializedName("end_date")
private Date endDate;
private Event event;

public Occurrence(Parcel in){
    readFromParcel(in);
}

/**
 * Clase para recuperar los datos de un parcel, IMPORTANTE leerlos en el mismo orden que se escribieron!
 * @param in Parcel con los datos a leer
 */
private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
    id = in.readInt();
    startDate = new Date(in.readLong());
    endDate = new Date(in.readLong());
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(id);
    dest.writeLong(startDate.getTime());
    if (endDate != null)
        dest.writeLong(endDate.getTime());
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Occurrence> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Occurrence>() {
    public Occurrence createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Occurrence(in);
    }

    public Occurrence[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Occurrence[size];
    }
};

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public Date getStartDate() {
    return startDate;
}
public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
}
public Date getEndDate() {
    return endDate;
}
public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
    this.endDate = endDate;
}
public Event getEvent() {
    return event;
}
public void setEvent(Event event) {
    this.event = event;
}
@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}
```

}

And the code when I try to pass the Array:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), MoreDatesAndPlacesActivity.class);
                intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("venues", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) currentEventModel.getVenues());
```

And the code when I try to get the array:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    List<Venue> venues = b.getParcelableArrayList("venues");
```

How can i solve this exception? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that this is happening when `endDate == null` in your `Occurrence` object. In this case, you're not writing a value to the Parcel, but the `readFromParcel()` method is still trying to read it.

Maybe something like the following will help:

```
private void readFromParcel(Parcel in)
{
    id = in.readInt();
    startDate = new Date(in.readLong());

    long date = in.readLong();
    if (date != 0L)
    {
        endDate = new Date(date);
    }
} 

public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)
{ 
    dest.writeInt(id); 
    dest.writeLong(startDate.getTime());

    if (endDate != null)
    {
        dest.writeLong(endDate.getTime());
    }
    else
    {
        dest.writeLong(0L);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, that worked for me. But that's a strange behavior because when i passed an Occurrence as parameter to an activity it worked.

Comment: Hmm... Are you sure the `Occurrence` object you passed didn't have the `endDate` set? 'cause if it did, then that exception wouldn't occur.

Comment: I'm 90% sure, that's why i put that validation "if endDate != null", because before that i receive an exception.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I was wondering why you were doing that check just on `endDate`. Well, I think the code above should prevent that, either way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use android studio plug in for make class as parcelable
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7332?pr=

Comment: Problem is in sequence of writing and reading of object...sequence should be same, as it is like reading file.